# Proof that the tangent space to an open submanifold can be identified with the tangent space to the whole manifold

Tags: general-topology, smooth-manifolds

I have one question about the proof given by John M. Lee in his book. Please find the sentence underlined with red in the following picture. How could Prof. Lee guarantee that such $B$ does exist? Thank you.

P.S. If I am not mistaken, $\overline{B}$ is the closure of $B$ in the space $M$.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that each (topological) manifolds is a *regular topological space*.

To see this, let $p \in M$ and let $U$ be an open neigbhorhood of $p$ in $M$. Choose an open $W \subset M$ such that $p \in W \subset U$ and $W$ is homeomorphic to an open subset $W' \subset \mathbb R^n$. Let $h : W \to W'$ be a homeomorphism. There exists an open ball $B_r(h(p))$ around $h(p)$ with radius $r > 0$ such that $B_r(h(p)) \subset W'$. Then $B' = B_{r/2}(h(p))$ has the property that $\overline{B'}$ is compact and $\overline{B'} \subset W'$. Now take $B = h^{-1}(B')$. This is an open subset of $W$, hence also an open subset of $M$. Note that $h^{-1}( \overline{B'})$ contains $B$ and is compact, hence closed in $M$ since $M$ is Hausdorff. Thus

$$p \in B' \subset \overline{B} \subset h^{-1}( \overline{B'}) \subset W \subset U .$$

Comment: In which step is the fact that $W\subseteq U$ being established? Thank you.

Comment: @Steve I forgot the condition $p \in W \subset U$. This can be achieved by starting with any open neigborhood $\tilde W$ of $p$ which is homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$. Now take $W = U \cap \tilde W$.